# Loading JSON file with repeating elements into hive table

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

Given this simple JSON file:

```
{
    "EVT": {
        "EVT_ID": "12345",
        "LINES": {
            "LINE": {
                "LINE_NUM" : 1,
                "AMT" : 100,
                "EVT_DT" : "2018-01-01"
            },
            "LINE": {
                "LINE_NUM" : 2,
                "AMT" : 150,
                "EVT_DT" : "2018-01-02"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We need to load that into a hive table.  The ultimate goal is to flatten the json, something like this:

```
+--------+----------+-----+------------+
| EVT_ID | Line_Num | Amt |   Evt_Dt   |
+--------+----------+-----+------------+
|  12345 |        1 | 100 | 2018-01-01 |
|  12345 |        2 | 150 | 2018-01-02 |
+--------+----------+-----+------------+
```

Here's my current DDL for the table:

```
create table foo.bar (
    `EVT` struct<
        `EVT_ID`:string,
        `LINES`:struct<
            LINE: struct<`LINE_NUM`: int,`AMT`:int,`EVT_DT`:string>
        >
    >)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe';
```

It seems like the second "line" is overwriting the first.  A simple select * from the table returns;

```
{"evt_id":"12345","lines":{"line":{"line_num":2,"amt":150,"evt_dt":"2018-01-02"}}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON and table definition are wrong. "Repeating elements" is an Array. LINES should be `array<struct>`, not `struct<struct>` (note square brackets):

```
{
    "EVT": {
        "EVT_ID": "12345",
        "LINES": [
             {
                "LINE_NUM" : 1,
                "AMT" : 100,
                "EVT_DT" : "2018-01-01"
            },
             {
                "LINE_NUM" : 2,
                "AMT" : 150,
                "EVT_DT" : "2018-01-02"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And you do not need this `"LINE":` also, because it is just an array element

Comment: Argh, I should have known that, thanks!  Of course that's not working for me either, but that's a job for another question.